# Serialize Objects with One-to-One Relationship Django

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie in django. I am working on a rest api. I have an optional "is a" relationship i.e Student is a Employee. I am trying to serialize these 2 models such that I get combined json result. Please let me know if anyone can help me with this. Thanks

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    email_id=models.EmailField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=11,blank=True)
    is_job_ready=models.BooleanField(False)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    location_preference=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    college=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_with_college=models.BooleanField()
    employee=models.OneToOneField(Employee,primary_key=True)
```

Comment: What does your serializer look like so far? And what output are you looking for?

Answer (score 19):

The [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) has some nice tools for serializing nested objects.

You need what they call a [Nested Relationship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). Like this -

```
from rest_framework import serializers

# define your models here ...

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = ('full_name', 'email_id', 'mobile_no', 'is_job_ready', 'type', 'location_preference')

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  employee = EmployeeSerializer(read_only = True)

  class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ('college', 'year', 'is_with_college', 'employee')
```

Then, you can load your serializer and use it something like this -

```
from myapp.models import StudentSerializer

student = Student.objects.first()
serializer = StudentSerializer(student)

serializer.data
# { 'college': 'Naropa University',
#    'is_with_college': True,
#    'year': '2015'}
#    'employee': {
#      'full_name' : 'Chogyam Trungpa',
#      'email_id' : 'teacher@naropa.edu',
#      'mobile_no' : '555-555-5555',
#      'is_job_ready' : True,
#      'type' :'Teacher',
#      'location_preference' : 'Boulder, CO'
#    }
#  }
```

Comment: I want to write an update for my serializer. The model has one to one relationship with other model. How should I accept the data and update my model  using serializer?

Comment: @KishanMehta http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Answer (score 2):

You can go with @metahamza way, or use `depth` keyword  refer docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

> Specifying nested serialization
> The default ModelSerializer uses primary keys for relationships, but you can also easily generate nested representations using the depth option:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created']
        depth = 1
```

> The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the `depth` of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a flat representation.