# EcomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mobile_number'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a user and link it with the user profile. But here is the problem.
This is my profile model

```
class EcomUser(BaseModelMixin):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True, blank=True, null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    signinId = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    GOOGLE = 'GOOGLE'
    APPLE = 'APPLE'
    MOBILE_NUMBER = 'mobile_number'
    LOGIN_TYPES = (
        (GOOGLE, 'GOOGLE'), 
        (APPLE, 'APPLE'), 
        (MOBILE_NUMBER, 'mobile_number')
    )
    loginType = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=LOGIN_TYPES, default=MOBILE_NUMBER)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "ecom_user"
```

My user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, BaseModelMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email_address',
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True,unique=True)
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True,unique=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # Email & Password are required by default.

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.fullName

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    objects = UserManager()
```

and serializer.py

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Normal serializer which accepts mobile number"""
    mobile_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, min_length=10, required=True)
    referral_code = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, min_length=10, required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255)


    def validate_referral_code(self, referral_code):
        if not re.match(r"^[\w]{10}$", referral_code):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Wrong Referral Code")
        return referral_code

    def validate_mobile_number(self, mobile_number):
        if not re.match(r"^[\d]{10}$", mobile_number):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please pass proper mobile number")
        return mobile_number

class EcomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    mobile_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, min_length=10, required=True)
    referral_code = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, min_length=10, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = EcomUser
        fields= ('profile_id','referral_code', 'mobile_number', 'loginType', 'signinId')
        
    def create(self, data):
        instance = EcomUser.objects.create(**data)
        return instance
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def registration(request):
    try:
        local_reponse = {
                "status": False,
                "message": "",
                "code": status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                "data": []
            }
        data = request.data
        print('1')
        mobile_number = data.get('mobile_number', None)
        referralCode = data.get('referralCode', '')
        LoginType = data.get('LoginType')
        signinId = data.get('signinId', '')
        email = data.get('email', '')
    
        print(f'{LoginType} --- {EcomUser.MOBILE_NUMBER}')
        if LoginType == "mobile_number":
            print('2')
            exist_user = User.objects.filter(mobile_number=mobile_number).count()
            if exist_user: 
                print('3')
                local_reponse["message"] = msg.ALREADY_EXIST
                return Response(local_reponse)
            try:
                print('not found')
                registerd_user = User.objects.get(mobile_number=mobile_number)
                print(f'{registerd_user} -- check')
                if registerd_user:
                    print('register')
                    ecom = EcomUser.objects.get(profile_id=registerd_user.id)
                    if ecom:
                        local_reponse["message"] = msg.ALREADY_EXIST

            except User.DoesNotExist:
                print('4')
                user = User.objects.create_ecom_user(mobile_number=mobile_number)
                user.save()
                print('is user create?')
                if user:
                    print('yes')
                    info = {}
                    info['profile_id'] = user.id
                    info['referral_code'] = referralCode
                    info['mobile_number'] = mobile_number
                    info['LoginType'] = LoginType
                    info['signinId'] = signinId
                    ecom_serializer = EcomUserSerializer(data=info)
                    if not ecom_serializer.is_valid():
                        print('5')
                        local_reponse["message"] = ecom_serializer.error_messages           
                        local_reponse["status"] = False,
                        return Response(local_reponse) 
                    print(f'linked profile 1 ----' )
                    
                    ecomuser_data = ecom_serializer.save()
                    print(f'linked profile 2 ---- ' )
                    ecomuser_id = ecomuser_data.id
                    print('linked profile 3' )
                    ecomuser = EcomUser.objects.get(id=ecomuser_id)
                    print('linked profile 4' )
                    ecom_serializer = EcomUserSerializer(ecomuser)
                    print('linked profile 5' )
                    context = ecom_serializer.data
                    print('linked profile 6' )
                    local_reponse = {
                        "status": True,
                        "message": msg.CREATED,
                        "code": status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        "data": context
                    }
                    print('linked profile 7' )
        
            return Response(local_reponse)
    except Exception as e:
        print('7')
        local_reponse["message"] = str(e)
        return Response(local_reponse)
```

When I try to run API on postman. It showed "EcomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mobile_number'" and the output in the terminal show below:

```
1
mobile_number --- mobile_number
2
not found
4
is user create?
yes
linked profile 1 ----
7
```

The user is created but can not link to the profile, any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no mobile_number field in your EcomUser model. Thus when you call

```
 ecomuser_data = ecom_serializer.save()
```

after adding

```
 info['mobile_number'] = mobile_number
```

if fails, leaving you with the user and no profile.  I guess is_valid() is only checking the fields it wants, not detecting the surplus, but the extra field causes the save to fail with the error shown.  You've already added the field when creating the user, so you don't need it in the profile, so removing that second line should make things work.

Comment: ah and one more thing, if i removed mobile_number in the profile model, how to get user profile with the mobile_number displayed?

Comment: Might be easier to ask another question as I don't have enough context to really answer. This question might help though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548337/serialize-objects-with-one-to-one-relationship-django